# Unity C# Object array in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build the following structure into the Unity inspector so I can add the necessary `Sprites` and `AudioClips`. I can build a simple `ArrayList` but not sure how to build with different levels.

```
Letters (size 28)

letter[0] {
    mainSprite {Sprite},
    letterSounds[3](size 3) { Sprite, Audioclip}, { Sprite, Audioclip}, { Sprite, Audioclip},
    animation {Animation}

letter[1] {
    mainSprite {Sprite},
    letterSounds[3](size 3) { Sprite, Audioclip}, { Sprite, Audioclip}, { Sprite, Audioclip},
    animation {Animation}

letter[2] {
    mainSprite {Sprite},
    letterSounds[3](size 3) { Sprite, Audioclip}, { Sprite, Audioclip}, { Sprite, Audioclip},
    animation {Animation}
```

This is what I have. But it is only one level. I have looked at tutorials but they only show add the depth in code. I want to add it to the Unity `[SerializeField]` inspector

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Point
{
   public List<Vector3> list;
   public Point()
   {
      list = new List<Vector3>();
    }
}

public class AlphaIntroController : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    public List<GameObject> myLists = new List<GameObject>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you want but I followed your Letters structure to produce this in the inspector:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class Letter
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct LetterSounds
    {
        public Sprite sprite;
        public AudioClip audioClip;
    }

    public Sprite mainSprite;
    public List<LetterSounds> letterSounds = new List<LetterSounds>();
    public Animation animation;
}

public class AlphaIntroController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Letter> letters = new List<Letter>();
}
```

[image: Letters structure]